# Mostrar el menú de un sitio web en otro distinto, ambos con wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Actualmente tengo dos sitios web: uno es corporativo (hecho con **wordpress**) y el otro es una red social (**wordpress y buddypress**).

Las direcciones son **refugees-welcome.es** (corporativo) y **redfugiados.refugees-welcome.es** (para la red social)Los tengo separados por cuestiones de seguridad, pero quiero que se pueda navegar entre ellos.

Así, me gustaría que en el menú del sitio corporativo apareciesen ciertos items solamente si un usuario ha iniciado sesión en la red social. Es decir, que se muestren o no elementos del menú de la web corporativa dependiendo de si los usuarios están logueados en la red social.

**¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?**

Muchas gracias por adelantado y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es ampliar la funcion de login de Wordpress y agregar tu propia `cookie`.

De manera que en cuanto alguien se identifique dentro de la red social (redfugiados.refugees-welcome.es) le pongas la `cookie` y al entrar en tu web, puedas leerla y mostrar las partes que quieras de la web.

Si tienes dudas sobre como hacerlo a nivel técnico, eso ya es otra pregunta.